# Post/Custom Post Type URL Access

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, urls, user-access

Is there a way to prevent people from visiting a post's permalink?

A lot of times we create posts or custom post types that end up being included as part of the content of a page or some other feature and are not always intended to be viewed individually.

A good example might be for a slideshow. You create a few posts where each individual post is the content of a slide in the slideshow. Each one of those posts has a unique permalink, something like `example.com/slide-one`. There's no reason for someone to be able to access that individual post so I would like to "hide" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expose the permalinks on the front end, then there's no way for someone to reach them, but if you want to absolutely prevent it then set `publicly_queryable` to false when you [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: Though someone could guess the URL.  But I guess that doesn't matter if the content is being exposed elsewhere on the website.  What about the default `post` type?  I might want to make some available and not others (probably through a category or tag).  Then where do I go from there?  Hook into `template_redirect`?

Comment: `template_redirect` would work, check if `is_single()`, fetch and check the categories or tags for the post, and maybe `wp_redirect( home_url() );` to send people away.